# Save every 5 seconds

Tags: ios, core-data, save, nstimer

I have a tableview where I can enter data and save it thanks to core data. I wanted to know what do I have to do so that every 5 seconds my data will "autosave" instead of clicking a save button.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave 
                                                                    target:self 
                                                                    action:@selector(save)];
}

- (void)save {

    [self setEditing:NO animated:YES];

    for (EditTableCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
        if ([cell isEditable])
            [self.managedObject setValue:[cell value] forKey:[cell key]];
    }

    [self saveManagedObjectContext];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: use `NSTimer` maybe but that'll be too heavy (_every 5 seconds? even when there are **no** changes?_)

Comment: why don't you save _after_ every changes, if that is desired feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @staticVoidMan mentioned in comments, use a NSTimer to save.  However, that frequency is very very fast.  I would at least do a call to `-[NSManagedObjectContext hasChanges]` so that you are not wasting even more cycles.

Comment: How do I call [NSManagedObjectContext hasChanges]?

Comment: That is a objective-c method signature.  It means there is an instance method called `-hasChanges` that you can call on the `NSManagedObjectContext` and if you look in the documentation it will return a `BOOL` telling you if there are changes or not.